# How to convert given below URL into query parameter using Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am new to servlet concept. My requirement is like converting restful given URL into query parameter in the body.

Given URL :

```
http://anydomain:8080/ServletBasics/HelloForm/India/Andhrapradesh
```

Required Output URL:

```
http://anydomain:8080/ServletBasics/HelloForm?Country=India&State=Andhrapradesh
```

URL fetching has been done by using given servlet code. Could anybody help me out to convert given URL into query based URL. Thanks

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws      ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><body>");
    String vid = request.getRequestURI();
    out.println("</body></html>");
    out.close();

}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

modified code: sdfd.java

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    String url = request.getRequestURI();
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body>");

if(url.equals("/servletTest/v1/code")) {    

    String[] words = url.split("/");
    String newURI = url.replace(url, "/ws/simple/Apicode?"+"first_name="+words[2]+"&"+"last_name="+words[3]);

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(newURI);
    rd.forward(request, response);

    out.println(newURI);


    }

    else 
    {
        out.println("bad");
    }



    out.println("</html>");
    out.println("</body>");

    out.close();
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>sdfd</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>sdfd</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>sdfd</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/v1/code</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am trying to convert

```
http://localhost:8080/servletTest/v1/code
```

to

```
http://localhost:8080/servletTest/ws/simple/Apicode?first_name=v1&last_name=code
```

but i am getting below error.

```
HTTP Status 404 - /servletTest/ws/simple/Apicode
type Status report
message /servletTest/ws/simple/Apicode
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

Kindly help me where exactly i am going wrong?
thanks

Comment: Do you have mapping for /ws/simple/Apicode

Answer (score 1):

use URLRewrite

You can find the documentation in following url : http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html

for example :

```
 <rule>
    <from>^/HelloForm/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$</from>
    <to>/HelloForm?Country=$1&State=$2</to>
</rule>
```

To configure UrlRewrite, read manual http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html

Comment: Hi Shashi,i went through the mentioned document. Good One. I am implementing in a different way. please find the below servlet and web.xml code. Here i am getting HTTP Status 404-The requested resource is not available.
Could you please help me out.